# How can I create table not declare column but copy from another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a stored procedure to return all column data from a table except one column that key of where condition. The original table will be change a lot during my project, so I don't want to create table with declaring columns. How can I create the table that columns are copy of another table? I'm using SQL Server.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SelectCharacterDataById] 
    @Id INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    CREATE TABLE #TempTable 
    AS 
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.CharacterData
        WHERE CharacterID = @Id 

    ALTER TABLE #TempTable
        DROP COLUMN CharacterID

    SELECT * 
    FROM #TempTable
END
```

Comment: Thats a very strange requirement given whoever is calling this SP can just ignore the unused column. The solution you have shown is the only way to accomplish that that I know of.

Comment: Oh you want `SELECT * INTO #TempTable`.

Comment: @Dale K I want to save network and memory resource to get those infos in my gameserver project. so, I try to zip packet datas. I solved this problem by  `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM dbo.CharacterData WHERE CharacterID = @Id` and drop the column! thank u!.

Comment: I suggest that its not worth the effort for a single column. Lots of columns maybe, but one? I can't imagine you would even notice the performance improvement.

Comment: @DaleK Yeah, I agree with that, I really don't know about database's drop column over head heavier or not than gameserver's overhead. so I'll test this with stresstest program. thank u for that sugeestion! : )

Comment: Have you tried to use dynamic sql?